# Is it better to redeclare a struct inside function or declare it static and set to 0 everytime?

Tags: c, struct, c99

Basically, if I have a struct like:

```
struct header {
  char ptr[512];
};
```

and I have a function like so:

```
void some_function() {
  struct header header = { 0 };

  // do something with struct
}
```

Would it actually benefit performance-wise to do it like this:

```
void some_function() {
  static struct header header;

  memset((char *)&header, 0, sizeof(header));
  // do something with struct
}
```

I know memset doesn't always work if the struct contains pointers since NULL might not be located at address 0x0000, but for this case when this doesn't matter, what is the better way to do it?

Comment: The idea that there is a "right" way to do this assumes there is a quick fix.  this is not the case in C.  In other languages that have been build to have quick init there is a way to do it.  In C there isn't.

Comment: The question asks which is better, not which is "right". It's a fair question. If your answer is it doesn't matter, mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: There's little practical difference between the two methods. Static variables are normally only used if you need to save the value between calls. If you're initializing the variable every time, and not returning a pointer to it, there's no reason to make it static.

Comment: ...unless it is very large and might break the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the C program specified an actual static object or an object automatically allocated on the stack, the performance of these two pieces of code would be nearly identical. There might be minuscule performance differences based on how one was addressed or some performance differences based on where they happened to be allocated with respect to other data and cache properties. (In particular, the automatic version might have better properties since the memory is not reserved exclusively for the structure. It would be shared with other data while other functions are executing instead of `some_function`, and therefore it might reside in cache more often and result in fewer memory accesses. Additionally, since it would be shared with other functions, the entire program might use less memory overall, which improves performance.)

However, C programs do not directly specify what a computer must do (although some C implementations may be implemented that way or have switches to do it, or something near it). Per the C standard, a C program specifies an imaginary computation in an abstract machine. The job of a C compiler is to translate that computation into a program for a real machine. It is given great latitude to do so.

One thing this means is that if a compiler and see and sufficiently analyze enough of the source code to see that the two versions of the function behave identically (in terms of *observable behavior*), it can translate them to identical code. (Observable behavior includes input and output interactions, access to volatile objects, and data written to files.) In that case, there is no performance difference.

If anything, the automatic version is easier for the compiler to analyze. It knows the automatic object will vanish (in the abstract machine) when the function ends. Although, in both cases you clear the object at the start of the function, so the compiler, assuming knowledge about `memset` has been built into it, knows the object begins anew in this regard each time the function starts, there are other ways the behavior could differ that a compiler writer has to worry about. For example, if the address of the static structure is taken, and especially if it is passed to any other routines, the compiler has to be concerned that the data in it might be used after the function returns, by other code that has retained the address of it. In contrast, for the automatic structure, the compiler may behave as if the automatic object is never used after the function returns because, in the abstract machine, it ceases to exist when the function returns. (Therefore, if any other code did retain its address, the use of that address is not defined by the C standard, and the compiler does not have to do anything for it.)

So, except in esoteric circumstances or mere happenstance of memory and cache behavior, we can generally expect the automatic version to be at least as good as the static version.

In general, write software to express what you need to—and only what you need to. If an object does not need to persist beyond the function’s lifetime, then leave it as an automatic object and do not make it static.

Note that it is often unnecessary to zero all of such a structure anyway, because:

- The part of the structure that is used might be indicated with a length or a sentinel (such as a null character marking the end), and so no software will attempt to read any later portion, so there is no need to initialize it.
- Or, if all of the structure will be read, then the software could be designed to fill in the non-zero part and then zero only the remaining part, instead of first zeroing the entire structure.

Comment: One question: You are mentioning the fact that the compiler might generate similar code for the two versions and they might have comparable results, but considering a structure big enough (512 bytes might not be considered big, but) isn't every stack allocation for automatic objects going to take a "huge" amount of time, compared to having the memory already reserved from the static object?

Comment: @AlexGh: Stack allocation for a 512-byte object typically requires at most one instruction: Subtract 512 from the stack pointer. Often it requires zero instructions because the compiler merely includes it in the subtraction already performed for the entire stack frame of the function.